# Centering bibliography title in biblatex - tried every suggestion on Google

Tags: biblatex, sectioning, horizontal-alignment

I know this question has answers on this site already, but none of them worked! I am using `biblatex` with the `historian` style for my history day paper. My teacher requires the bibliography heading be centered over the bibliography, and try as I might I can't do it! I tried wrapping `\printbibliography` with centering and redefining the bibliography string used by `biblatex`  and even redefining `\bibname` but nothing works. Here's my code (you can try it with your own .bib file to get an output):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [american]{babel}
\usepackage [babel=once, english=american] {csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=historian,sorting=nty, autocite=footnote,
babel=hyphen, mincrossrefs=1,usetranslator=true,printseries]{biblatex}

\nocite{*}
\bibliography{bib.bib}
\setlength\bibitemsep{2\itemsep}
\setlength\bibhang{30pt}

%This is one of many things I tried that didn't work. If I just change the spelling of bibliography it works fine, but it ignores the centering command.
%\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
%  references = {\begin{center}Bibliography\end{center}},
%}     

\begin{document}
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[keyword=primary,heading=subbibliography,title={Primary Sources}]
\printbibliography[keyword=secondary,heading=subbibliography,title={Secondary Sources}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use `memoir`, you probably want to use the command `\setsecheadstyle`.  If other sectional divisions earlier in the document need to be done differently, then add before you call your `\print*` commands something like `\setsecheadstyle{\centering\bfseries\itshape}` (for centred, bold, italic *section*-level heading).  For `\subsection`s, you use the command `\setsubsecheadstyle`.  Of course, if all section headings should be styled the same, just set it once in the preamble.

Comment: Do you only need to centre the bibliography heading?

Comment: @jon You seem to have the answer there. Would you mind turning your comment into an actual answer?

Comment: @moewe -- Wow. An old one....

Comment: @jon Indeed. Thank you for taking time to answer this one.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things you could do. (I show two of them.) Since you are using `memoir`, you have access to a fairly easy set of commands to control section headings. Chapters are more complicated, but there are some pre-defined styles that might fit your needs (e.g., `crosshead`, `culver`, and `dash`).

Anyway, using `memoir`, you have the commands `\setSheadstyle` (where `S` represents `sec` for sections, `subsec` for subsections, etc.). Note that this command only affects the styling: for spacing, there are a series of other commands. `\secSheadstyle` can be used at different points in the document. Below, I suggested you try

```
\setsecheadstyle{\centering\large\bfseries\itshape}
```

and

```
\setsecheadstyle{\centering\itshape}
```

`biblatex`, on the other hand, has `\defbibheading`, which has two mandatory and one optional argument. In the below example, we have:

```
\defbibheading{rene}[\bibname]{% or try `\refname`; both can be redefined
  \section*{#1}% 
  \markboth{#1}{#1}}
```

So, for example, you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% usually a good idea for pdflatex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=once, english=american]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=historian,sorting=nty, autocite=footnote,
babel=hyphen, mincrossrefs=1,usetranslator=true,printseries]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}% the command \bibliography is deprecated
\setlength\bibitemsep{2\itemsep}
\setlength\bibhang{30pt}

\defbibheading{rene}[\bibname]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \markboth{#1}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
% un-redefined \section style
\section{Default Section Style}

% now we redefine styling of \section
\setsecheadstyle{\centering\large\bfseries\itshape}
\printbibheading[heading=rene]
\setsecheadstyle{\centering\itshape}
\printbibliography[keyword=primary,heading=subbibliography,title={Primary Sources}]
\printbibliography[keyword=secondary,heading=subbibliography,title={Secondary Sources}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Any idea's on how to make this work for report doc type? '''
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=apa,
citestyle= authoryear, %authoryear
natbib, %or chicago-authordate,
sorting=nyt,
hyperref=true
]{biblatex} '''